# Lodash filter unique documents

Tags: filter, lodash

How can I filter the current data:

```
[{
    key: 'T1',
    legs:[{ fno: 'W321',date: '2017-01-02 18:20:00.000+0200'}],
    fare: { type: 'B', price: 25 }
},{
    key: 'T1',
    legs:[{ fno: 'W321', date: '2017-01-02T18:20:00.000+0200'}],
    fare: { type: 'E', price: 23 }
},{
    key: 'T1',
    legs:[{ fno: 'W321', date: '2017-01-02T18:20:00.000+0200'}],
    fare: { type: 'E', price: 20}
}]
```

I want to group by `legs[0].fno`, `legs[0].date` and `fare.type`, and keep the lowest priced items in each group. This is the expected result:

```
[{
    key: 'T1',
    legs:[{ fno: 'W321',date: '2017-01-02T18:20:00.000+0200'}],
    fare: { type: 'B', price: 25}
},{
    key: 'T1',
    legs:[{ fno: 'W321',date: '2017-01-02T18:20:00.000+0200'}],
    fare: { type: 'E',  price: 20}
}]
```

Comment: remove high price inside same legs.fno and legs.date and fare.type records

Comment: same legs.fno , legs.date and fare.type

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.groupBy()` with a callback to create a string to group by, then `_.map()` each group to a single item using [`_.minBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4):

```js
var data = [{"key":"T1","legs":[{"fno":"W321","date":"2017-01-02 18:20:00.000+0200"}],"fare":{"type":"B","price":25}},{"key":"T1","legs":[{"fno":"W321","date":"2017-01-02T18:20:00.000+0200"}],"fare":{"type":"E","price":23}},{"key":"T1","legs":[{"fno":"W321","date":"2017-01-02T18:20:00.000+0200"}],"fare":{"type":"E","price":20}}];

var result = _(data)
  // group by the combined group keys
  .groupBy(function(o) {
    // extract all group keys and join them to a string
    return _.at(o, ['key', 'legs[0].date', 'fare.type']).join('');
  })
  .map(function(group) {
     // get the object object with the minimum fare.price
     return _.minBy(group, 'fare.price');
   })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How about replacing the reduce function just by a simple _.minBy? Saves a couple of lines.

Comment: Thanks @MauritsRijk for the `_.minBy()` idea. I've updated the answer.